# dict.get() always checks for the default value even if not necessary

Tags: python, dictionary, get

Why does the method have to validate the optional (default value) argument if the first argument already produces a return?

```
my_dict = {'subject': 'title'}
subject = my_dict.get('subject', my_dict['Subject'])
```

returns: "KeyError: 'Subject'"

Alternatively, I'd go with the following to account for variations in the key name (outside of my control):

```
subject = my_dict['subject'] if 'subject' in my_dict else my_dict['Subject']
```

I'm just curious why the get() method behaves the way it does.

Comment: I prefer the dict.get() method over the alternative for improved readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default argument will be evaluated before passing to the `my_dict.get`.  This is completely generic for how functions are called (their arguments must all be evaluated before the call is performed).
There is nothing *inside* the implementation of `get` that is causing this behaviour.

You could possibly write your own dictionary sub-class with a lazy evaluation getter function that takes a callable as its second argument, and only calls the callable if needed:

```
class Dict(dict):

    def lazy_get(self, key, func):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        else:
            return func()

my_dict = Dict({'subject': 'title'})

subject = my_dict.lazy_get('subject', lambda: my_dict['Subject'])
print(subject)  # prints 'title'

subject2 = my_dict.lazy_get('foo', lambda: my_dict['subject'])
print(subject2)  # also prints 'title'
```

In the specific case where you have a list of keys to try, you could do something like this instead:

```
class Dict(dict):

    def get_from_keys(self, keys, default=None):
        for key in keys:
            if key in self:
                return self[key]
        return default

my_dict = Dict({'subject': 'title'})

subject = my_dict.get_from_keys(['subject', 'Subject'])
print(subject)

subject2 = my_dict.get_from_keys(['foo', 'subject'])
print(subject2)
```

And of course, there is nothing to say that either of the above functions have to be class methods. You could use an ordinary dictionary and a separate, standalone function:

```
def get_from_keys(dct, keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        if key in dct:
            return dct[key]
    return default

my_dict = {'subject': 'title'}

subject = get_from_keys(my_dict, ['subject', 'Subject'])
print(subject)

subject2 = get_from_keys(my_dict, ['foo', 'subject'])
print(subject2)
```